# AddressInUseException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc

We have 1 .NET project on windows server and multiple developers are working on this project. All developers are accessing the project from different locations on same window server.

As the 1 port is assigned to the project, when multiple developers run/debug the application they face the below exception.

```
System.IO.IOException
  HResult=0x80131620
  Message=Failed to bind to address https://127.0.0.1:7085: address already in use.
  Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.<BindEndpointAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.LocalhostListenOptions.<BindAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.<BindAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.<BindAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<BindAsync>d__33.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<StartAsync>d__30`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.<StartAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.Run(String url)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in D:\New folder\WebApp\WebApp\Program.cs:line 67

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
AddressInUseException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

Inner Exception 2:
SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

So alternative is all developers need to change the port of their respective project though actually project is same and debug. But this is not expected or is it really?

Do we have any other alternative other than changing the port for each developer?

Comment: You can try to use proxy or Docker container.

Comment: You can use [launchsettings.json](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/asp-net-core-launchsettings-json-file/) to specify the launch Url / port with multiple different launch profiles.

Comment: So do you mean to say that launchsettings.json will be different for multiple developers? We use version control. So if all are working on the same version then this project file will be different for all and all other project files will be same.

Comment: I could not understand on proxy. How it will be related. Docker container is something that I need to check.

Comment: @Mack  One `LaunchSettings.json` but different [profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson)